# Como hacer multiples UPDATE en un PROCEDURE de MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

como hago para hacer que dos o mas UPDATE se ejecuten en un mismo PROCEDURE.

```
CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE sp_anularFacturaBoleta(
    IN idFacturaBoleta VARCHAR(11)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE detalle_factura_boleta SET cantidad = 0, precio_venta = 0, valor_venta = 0 WHERE id_factura_boleta = idFacturaBoleta;
    UPDATE factura_boleta SET subtotal = 0, igv = 0, total = 0, id_orden_pedido = '' WHERE id_factura_boleta = idFacturaBoleta;
END
```

Comment: Saca los ; después de cada UPDATE

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE factura_boleta SET subtotal = 0, igv = 0, total = 0, id_orden_pedido = ''' at line 6

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo para que te guíes respecto a la tarea que deseas realizar

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_clients(@table1_id INT, @table2_id INT, @value1 VARCHAR(20), @value2 VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE clients
    SET    client_name = @value1
    WHERE id = @table⁯1_id

    UPDATE salesmen
    SET salesman_name = @value2     
    WHERE id = @table2_id
END
```

Donde como notas dentro de los paréntesis del SP declaro los nombres de los id de las tablas que usaré para hacer la operación de `WHERE`, así mismo declaro los nombres y tipo de las variables que van a recibir los datos que serán actualizados

Ya por dentro del SP declaro los 2 `UPDATE`, espero el ejemplo te sea útil para guiarte

Comment: entiendo tu estructura, pero en mi caso quiero enviar un solo parametro, ya que ambas consultas manejan un mismo ID.